# Concatenating tuples as types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I'm trying to practice some template programming. Maybe there's a standard way to do this, and I would be thankful for such answers, but my main goal is to practice the template programming techniques, so I tried to implement it myself:

I need to concatenate multiple tuples, but as types, not like `std::cat_tuple` does it. So I need something like `cat<std::tuple<int, float>, std::tuple<char, bool>, ...>` to get `std::tuple<int, float, char, bool, ...>` as a type.

My current attempt failed with a `is not a template` error:

```
/* Concat tuples as types: */
template <typename first_t, typename... rest_t> struct cat {
    using type = typename _cat<first_t, typename cat<rest_t...>::type>::type;
                          ^^^^ cat is not a template
};
template <typename first_t, typename second_t>
struct cat<first_t, second_t> {
    using type = typename _cat<first_t, second_t>::type;
                          ^^^^ cat is not a template
};
// Concat two tuples:
template <typename, typename> struct _cat;
template <typename tuple_t, typename first_t, typename... rest_t>
struct _cat<tuple_t, std::tuple<first_t, rest_t...>> {
    using type = typename _cat<typename append<first_t, tuple_t>::type, std::tuple<rest_t...>>::type;
};
template <typename tuple_t, typename first_t>
struct _cat<tuple_t, std::tuple<first_t>> {
    using type = typename append<first_t, tuple_t>::type;
};
// Prepend element to tuple:
template <typename, typename> struct prepend;
template <typename elem_t, typename... tuple_elem_t>
struct prepend<elem_t, std::tuple<tuple_elem_t...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<elem_t, tuple_elem_t...>;
};
// Apppend element to tuple:
template <typename, typename> struct append;
template <typename elem_t, typename... tuple_elem_t>
struct append<elem_t, std::tuple<tuple_elem_t...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<tuple_elem_t..., elem_t>;
};
```

What may be causing the error?

Is this a good approach? It might be solved in a simpler way, but I wanted it to be multi-purpose (with the append/prepend operations etc.).

Comment: `_cat` is undefined at the point of usage (it is defined only after the templates, that use it).

Comment: After [reordering](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fee31b995533096) the definition a little, it works fine. Your approach looks fine to me.

Comment: Ah sure... Those were previously implemented as methods inside a class, so the order didn't matter. Thanks. Sometimes the problem is just too simple to be found after hours of staring at the screen and trying to find a complex problem.

Comment: *"Maybe there's a standard way to do this"* There is. You can do `decltype` on the result of `std::cat_tuple`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After [reordering](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fee31b995533096) the definition a little, your code works fine.

I don't think that there are any guidelines for template meta programming. Probably due to the fact that the C++ committee is enhancing TMP "aggressively" and too few people is using TMP.

Here is my version of `Cat`, it basically follows the same structure as yours:

```
template <class, class>
struct Cat;
template <class... First, class... Second>
struct Cat<std::tuple<First...>, std::tuple<Second...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<First..., Second...>;
};
```

Answer (score 12):

How about a one-liner direct template aliase:

```
template<typename ... input_t>
using tuple_cat_t=
decltype(std::tuple_cat(
    std::declval<input_t>()...
));


tuple_cat_t<
    std::tuple<int,float>,
    std::tuple<int>
    > test{1,1.0f,2};
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Yes: was so incredibly simple.

Comment: Missing simple things is a very common habit of any active minds.

Comment: Nice. Similar solution was proposed by @HolyBlackCat in the comments, but I didn't know about the declval function. Without it it wouldn't be possible to solve this without constructing the types.

Comment: One addition is that I fixed a typo: its tuple_cat (not cat_tuple). declval is not a keyword; without it we'd need to copy its implementation (which is of-course a bit tricky).

Answer (score 4):

Is too late to play?

I propose the following solution

```
template <typename T, typename ...>
struct cat
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename ...> class C,
          typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2, typename ... Ts3>
struct cat<C<Ts1...>, C<Ts2...>, Ts3...>
   : public cat<C<Ts1..., Ts2...>, Ts3...>
 { };
```

Observe that this solution doesn't works only with a variadic list of `std::tuple` but also with a generic container of types. If a `std::tuple`-only solution is enough for you, you can simplify it as follows

```
template <typename T, typename ...>
struct cat
 { using type = T; };

template <typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2, typename ... Ts3>
struct cat<std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>, Ts3...>
   : public cat<std::tuple<Ts1..., Ts2...>, Ts3...>
 { };
```

You can test that works with

```
   using t1 = typename cat<std::tuple<int, float>,
                           std::tuple<char, bool>,
                           std::tuple<long, char, double>>::type;

   using t2 = std::tuple<int, float, char, bool, long, char, double>;

   static_assert(std::is_same<t1, t2>::value, "!");
```

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by `felix` (thanks!) with my precedent solution we have that

```
std::is_same<int, typename cat<int>::type>::value == true
```

that is... `cat<T>::type` is defined also when `T` isn't a `std::tuple`.

This is a problem?

I don't know because I don't know how is used `cat<T>::type`.

Anyway... avoid it imposing that `cat<Ts...>::type` is defined only when all `Ts...` are type containers (with the same container), it's simple: the main version for `cat` become only declared but not defined

```
template <typename, typename ...> // or also template <typename...>
struct cat;
```

and is introduced an additional specialization with a single type (but only when it's a type container).

```
template <template <typename ...> class C, typename ... Ts1>
struct cat<C<Ts1...>>
 { using type = C<Ts1...>; };
```

Comment: @JeJo - well... doesn't answer the first question ("What may be causing the error?") but I hope is a decent answer for the second one.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. It's a bit beyond of my experience with template programming, but I guess it's a reason to keep practicing. Thanks

Comment: Stylish! But wouldn't that `cat<int>::type` works potentially makes the compilation fail too late?

Comment: @felix - Interesting doubt. Well, `cat<int>::type` is defined and is `int`. This can be a problem? I don't know because I don't know where is used `cat<int>::type`. If used in a context where is required only a `std::tuple`, the fail should be immediate and relativeli simple to understand. If used in a context where a `int` isn't an error... I suppose almost everything can happens. Uhmmm... Maybe I can propose a version that check if first element is a `std::tuple` (but losing elegance :( ).

Comment: Yes, I think that you sacrifice some restriction for elegance too. Not necessarily immediately though, it may pass several layers of template and fail miles away where it is eventually used. Flexibility comes with a price, just like `void *`.

Comment: @McSim - answer improved following the felix's doubt.

Comment: @McSim - give also a look at Red.Wave's answer: completely different but extremely simple.