# C++ parameter pack of parameter packs?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, typelist

My objective is to build type lists by merging.
The ultimate goal is to build a compile time type dependency library.

Is it possible to construct parameter packs of parameter packs in C++?

```
// definition of a type list
template <typename...> struct sektyp;

template <> struct sektyp<> {};

template <typename Head, typename... Tails> struct sektyp<Head, Tails...> {
    using head = Head;
    using tails = sektyp<Tails...>;
};

// merge two type lists
template <typename... ST1, typename... ST2>
struct sektypmerge<sektyp<ST1...>, sektyp<ST2...>> {
    using result_type = sektyp<ST1..., ST2...>;
};

// merge three type lists 
template <typename... ST1, typename... ST2,typename... ST3>
struct sektypmerge<sektyp<ST1...>, sektyp<ST2...>,sektyp<ST3...> {
    using result_type = sektyp<ST1..., ST2...,ST3...>;
};

// merge N type lists...?
```

Merge N lists:

```
using integers = sektyp<int, unsigned>;
using reals = sektyp<float, double>;
using strings = sektyp<std::string>;
using irs=sektypmerge<integers,reals,strings>::result_type;
```

Now instead of integers, reals, strings you have 134 type lists. How do you do it?

EDIT: float (not short, of course)

Thank you

Tried several type list libraries on Github and Stackoverflow, but none could merge an arbitrary number of type lists.

Comment: Do one of these answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398815 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394684

Comment: `template <typename First, typename... Rest> struct sektypmerge { using result_type = typename merge2<First, typename sektypemerge<Rest...>::result_type>::result_type; };` You already know how to write `merge2`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, how about the general case (e.g. 936 type lists)? You need a parameter pack of parameter packs. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: No you do not need a parameter pack of parameter packs. `sektypmerge` I showed would work with an arbitrary number of parameters, each of which is a `sektyp<...>` with some arbitrary number of its own parameters.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tjn997Ea3)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks, that's perfect. I also changed short to float (apologize for that)